# Does the linearized system accurately describe the local behavior near the equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

For this nonlinear system, does the linearized system accurately describe the local behavior near the equilibrium points?

\begin{cases} x' = x + y^2 \\\\
y' = 2y \\\\
\end{cases}

The nonlinear system has an equilibrium point at $ (0, 0) $ and so I linearize this nonlinear system into
\begin{cases} x' = x \\\\
y' = 2y \\\\
\end{cases}

and essentially solving $ AX = X' $ where $ \displaystyle A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}, $ which I find the general solution to be $ \displaystyle \alpha e^{2t}[0, 1]^T + \beta e^t[1, 0]^T $ where $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ are arbitrary constants. But how do I know if this linearized system accurately describes the local behavior near the equilibrium points or not?

Comment: It's a hyperbolic equilibrium (the eigenvalues have nonzero real part), and this guarantees that the linear approximation is good. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Equilibrium#Hyperbolic_Equilibria

Answer (score 1):

I would just plot the vector field, and see if the linearization describes the solution near the critical point

[image]